# How to display sin as a number

Tags: simplifying-expressions

This seems like a basic question, but it drives me crazy....

How can I make Mathematica display the result as a number without trying to "simplify" it.

For example

```
Sin[Pi/7]
```

is displayed as Sin[Pi/7] for me and

```
Sin[Pi/5]
```

is displayed as a combination of radicals

I just need real numbers please

Comment: `N` that gives a numerical value: `N@Sin[Pi/7]`

Comment: `Sin[Pi/5.0]` forces numerical evaluation.

Comment: `Sin[Pi/7.]` also gives a numerical value (notice the `.` after the `7` - this is because as soon as there is any machine precision number in your expression (the `7.` here), Mathematica will convert everything to machine precision

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Victor, Chris, and Lukas !

Comment: You just discovered one of the major differences between Matlab and Mathematica :)

Comment: Look at "Exact and Approximate Results" in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html